# 'runin' shaped section title prints on same line as table of contents title

Tags: titlesec

I am using `titleformat` from the `titlesec` package to format section titles such that they don't cause new lines. However, when the table of contents is built, the first section appears on the same line as the contents titles. How can I cause all sections in the table of contents to appear on their own lines? Minimal code to replicate the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection. }{0pt}{}[]

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{Section A}
    \section{Section B}
\end{document}
```

[image: Table of contents with misprinted section]

Comment: thw sections in the table of contents do appear on their own lines, but you have specified the Contents section heading is run-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that in the article class, the table of contents is a section One possible solution is to define a different formatting for unnumbered sections:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection. }{0pt}{}[]
\titleformat{name=\section, numberless}[block]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}[]

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \section{Section A}
    \section{Section B}

\end{document}
```

[image]